# Removing .php extension from URL (.htaccess)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I've been trying to remove the .php endings from the my URLs with this code, but it's not working. This is my .htaccess file:

```
# Apache Rewrite Rules
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /

  # Add trailing slash to url
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

  # Remove .php-extension from url
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
 RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 

  # End of Apache Rewrite Rules
</IfModule>
```

I put that file into my public_html folder. For some reason it's still displaying `example.com/index.php` instead of `example.com/index`. Any clue why?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```